# postman duplicate collection / export + re-import

Tags: duplicates, postman

relatively new to Postman, having problem with the following simple scenario - I have a collection of Postman requests that all point to a local IP where I am developing my application. Let's suppose I finished my local development, deployed the application on some other server, and want to repeat the requests I previously created on THAT server. I know that probably one way to do this would be to use variables.

Instead of that, though, I did an export of the collection, and did a manual edit of the exported JSON file, replacing all the old local IP's with the new server IP. Also changed the collection name, and ID to something arbitrary. While the import back to Postman works, and I see the requests, they all have the old IP still hanging there, as if my replace didn't work, or as if Postman somehow caches the requests and thinks that that new collection is the same as the old one. I also tried "Duplicating" a collection and exporting the duplicated one / replacing / importing again - but the behavior seems to be the same.

Did I miss something, or should I approach what I want to do differently?
Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason for not using variables?

Comment: no reason - it's just because I didn't know how to use them - I wondered why the above quick (and dirty?) way wouldn't work - if for some reason the only way to do this is using variables then this should be the accepted answer

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing when you're trying to describe the things you're changing, rather than show the actual file changes. Also, just seems like work for no reason, variables were designed for this reason. Why do it all manually? :)

Comment: okay, I found what I was doing wrong - will post is as another answer - could you though post a suggestion to use variables as an answer so I could accept it? if you think it's too trivial, I'm okay with that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duh, I am dumb enough to have been substituting the "raw" URL, while right below there were the old values for "host" and "port" that are the ones Postman constructs URL from:

```
 {
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "1499274a-07bc-4ed2-87d4-b10d0cef8f8f",
        "name": "some-collection-DEVSERVER",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "login (success - bad locale)",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\n\t\"username\" : \"TEST\",\n\t\"password\" : \"123456\",\n\t\"locale\" : \"asd\"\n}"
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://SERVER-IP:SERVER-PORT/new-path/login",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "127",
                        "0",
                        "0",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    "port": "8081",
                    "path": [
                        "old-path",
                        "login"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
      ...
   ]
}
```

So, after suggestion to use variables I ended up creating two Collection variables "base-URL-LOCAL" and "base-URL-SERVER", that play the role of constants, and a third variable "base-url" which e.g. could have the value of {{base-URL-LOCAL}} (both initial and current values have to be updated). In my exported JSON collection, i substituted all "url" elements with something like the following:

```
"url": {
    "raw": "{{base-url}}/login",
    "host": [
        "{{base-url}}"
    ],
    "path": [
        "login"
    ]
}
```

That way somebody who gets my collection won't have to have pre-defined environments set up, and will have to edit collection variables, setting e.g. base-url to {{base-URL-SERVER}}